# Как сделать проверку элементов словаря менее громоздкой?

Tags: python, словари, словарь

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы код после проверки выполнялся, если все элементы словаря имели значение 0. Как сделать код не таким громоздким?

```
if (dictionary['first'] == 0 and
        dictionary['second'] == 0 and
        dictionary['third'] == 0 and
        dictionary['fourth'] == 0 and
        dictionary['fifth'] == 0 and
        dictionary['sixth'] == 0 and
        dictionary['seventh'] == 0):
            print(0)
```

Проверка элементов циклом for возвращает True, если хоть один элемент = 0, а мне нужно, чтобы возвращало True, только если ВСЕ элементы = 0

```
for v in dictionary.values():
    if v == 0:
        print(0)
```

Или

```
for k in dictionary.keys():
    if dictionary[k] == 0:
         print(0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте `any()`. Возвращает `True`, если хоть один из элементов имеет значение `true`. Т.к. требуется наоборот, то нужно подставить `not`:

```
if not any(d.values()):
```

PS. Здесь используется то, что 0 имеет логическое значение `False`.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 3):

А если был бы не `0`, а какое-то другое число `n` то в общем случае проверять можно было бы так:

```py
if all(x == n for x in dictionary.values()):
```

`all` проверяет, что условие выполняется для всех элементов, причём, если один из элементов проверку не проходит, то проверка прекращается досрочно (аналог досрочного завершения цикла через `break`).

Answer (score 2):

полагаю, можно сделать флаг вот так:

```
 all_null = True

 for key in dict:
  if dict[key] != 0:
    all_null = False
    break

 if all_null: # TODO
```

Comment: плюс я поставил, так как менее громоздко, но всё же это тоже достаточно многострочно, тут - на одну строку дел:-)

Answer (score 1):

Например, так можно бы (получаем список значений словаря, суммируем, проверяем на равенство 0), но как указали в комментариях, идея плохая - при +1 и -1 тоже будет 0. Так что это пример, как коротко делать не надо:-)

```
if not sum (dictionary.values()):
    print(0)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Не за что. Аж три варианта теперь и сразу:-) Выбирайте самый подходящий, принимайте, как ответ:-) (галочка под треугольником).

Comment: Но вообще этот вариант во-первых не может завершиться досрочно в отличие от проверок `all`/`any`, а во-вторых если в словаре возможны отрицательные элементы, то будет неправильный ответ в случае парных ключей с `+` и `-`, ну в общем возможны случаи, когда сумма `0`, а элементы не `0`

Comment: @CrazyElf, значит, самый подходящий ответ - ваш:-) Я не знал про any (), теперь буду знать, спасибо. И мой ответ был строго на 0 "заточен", про другие проблемы я понимал.

Comment: @Сергей Конкретно с проверкой именно на 0 оптимален ответ Эникейщика - он самый короткий )  Так то `any`/`all` при использовании **с генераторами** - штука очень полезная. Это как делать в цикле `break` для досрочного завершения.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, я перепутал. Я про any (), когда писал, уже видел тот вариант, но не помотрел, что не вы его написали. И за all () тоже спасибо с плюсом:-)

Comment: Плохое решение. Пример: несколько элементов равны 1, столько же равны -1. Сумма в итоге равна 0, хотя ни один из элементов не равен 0.

Comment: @Сергей Впрочем, я наврал, это не только с генераторами полезно, просто с генераторами и оставшиеся числа можно не генерить, а с готовыми коллекциями мы просто экономим на оставшихся проверках, ну, это тоже экономия.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а, да, верно, спасибо. Что-то я ступил. Ответ не удалю, чтобы эту переписку не удалять (удалил даже, и тут увидел, что все пропало), но отмечу, что неверный.